# Нужна ли запятая? И какое правило здесь действует?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, и

Поделись с другом своими идеями(,) и предложи ему поделиться своими.

Answer (score 4):

Запятая здесь **не нужна**, поскольку это **простое предложение** с двумя однородными сказуемыми с союзом *и* между ними.